# How to configure EventBridge to enable end users to schedule my Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on a serverless application that involves a AWS Lambda functions. I want to give my end users the ability to schedule the execution of one of my Lambda functions through AWS EventBridge. However, I'm not quite sure how to set up the configuration to allow this functionality.

Here are the specific requirements I'm trying to achieve:

1. Each end user should be able to schedule the Lambda function to run at a specific time or on a recurring schedule.
2. The scheduling process should be done programmatically from my application, not through the AWS Management Console.

I've already set up the Lambda function and tested it manually, but I'm unsure about the steps required to allow end users to schedule it dynamically. I believe I need to use EventBridge rules, but I'm not sure about the best approach to achieve this securely and efficiently.

Could someone guide me through the steps to set up the EventBridge configuration correctly for this scenario? Any code examples, tutorials, or documentation links would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.

1. Create an "admin" Lambda function that users invoke to create a schedule. The admin function would use the [AWS SDK (Boto)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/scheduler/client/create_schedule.html) to create and manage the schedule for your application function.
2. Create an admin Step Function and use the direct integration to create and manage schedules for the application function.